# How to understand suspicious syntax application by the Sagemath library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, sage

I'm using Sagemath / Cocalc (feel free to run it in your [browser](https://cocalc.com/app?anonymous=true), no sign-up no nothing required). As far as I understand, Sagemath is just a library on top of Python and the Sagemath notebook implicitly imports many things from the Sagemath library.

What puzzles me though is the following syntax:

```
R.<x,y> = AA[]
I = R.ideal(x^2 * y - 18,x * y^3  - 24, x * y - 6)
I.variety()
```

(This solves the system of polynomials `x^2 * y - 18=0,  x * y^3  - 24=, x * y - 6=0`, and returns `x=2,y=3`, nice!)

Running `type(AA)`, I see that it is

```
<class 'sage.rings.qqbar.AlgebraicRealField_with_category'>.
```

Running `type(R)`, I see that it is

```
<class 'sage.rings.polynomial.multi_polynomial_ring.MPolynomialRing_polydict_domain_with_category'>
```

Ok, b what does it mean in Python to use brackets `[]` at a class, i.e. `AA[]`?

What does it mean, in Python's syntax, to do `R.<x,y>`? Mind you, I haven't defined previously `x` and `y` as strings or anything, so this syntax seems very weird to me.

Comment: Does really no one have an idea? I can't imagine that this question is so hard...

Comment: may be the AA[] is a matrix as the function declare as polynomial one.

Comment: This isn't Python syntax. Sagemath may be implementing its own `type` function in terms of Python's `type` and exposing classes through its own syntax, but Python itself doesn't allow empty brackets or whatever `R.<x,y>` is.

Comment: I've added the `[sage]` tag in hopes that it will attract the attention of someone who knows that this code means.

Answer (score 4):

SageMath is built on top of Python, but it preparses input, and this is an example. Within SageMath:

```
sage: preparse('R.<x,y> = AA[]')
"R = AA['x, y']; (x, y,) = R._first_ngens(2)"
```

- The `preparse` command tells you how Sage will convert the string before evaluating it as standard Python.
- The `__getitem__` method (which is what gets called when you do `AA[args]`) for rings like `AA` creates a polynomial ring with the named generators.
- So `R.<x,y> = AA[]` creates a polynomial ring, and also defines `R`, `x`, and `y` as the ring and its two generators.

You can achieve the same thing by `R.<x,y> = PolynomialRing(AA)`.

Comment: See https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/repl/sage/repl/preparse.html#sage.repl.preparse.preparse_generators for the relevant function.